# How do I use the version of sqlite3 that comes with the Python installation with web.py?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web.py, python-2.7

I'm going through the web.py 0.3 tutorials and once I get [here](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en#databasing) I `import sqlite3` and set `dbn='sqlite3'` but it won't work.  Has anyone done this before?

Edit - I figured it out.  I used the code in the link posted by John and made the following script:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('c:\users\user\py\database')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''
CREATE TABLE todo (id integer primary key, title text, created date, done boolean default 'f');
''')
c.execute('''
CREATE TRIGGER insert_todo_created after insert on todo
begin
update todo set created = datetime('now')
where rowid = new.rowid;
end;
''')

c.execute('''
insert into todo (title) values ('Learn web.py');
''')

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: What OS are you on? if not on Windows or Mac, what Linux distribution is it?  Furthermore, is it python 2.5 or higher?  Even if it is 2.5 or higher, if you don't compile your python with sqlite3 support, you won't have it.

Comment: It's 2.7 32-bit and I'm on Windows 7.  Also I got it to work with Django, so I'm pretty sure I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend. Look at [this](http://kzar.co.uk/blog/view/web.py-tutorial-sqlite).

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be just `dbn='sqlite'`?